# how to export vb log data to excel

Tags: vb.net

The following code renames .wav files sequentially.

How do I **generate a log** of the original and its corresponing renamed file, and pend that data to a spreadsheet [ excel, (in the background)  ]. By background, I mean without excel opening up.

Something like, A1 cell in excel depicts original file name, and B1 cell depicts renamed file name, as in attached image.

[image]

Thank you.

```
Dim sourcePath As String = "E:\testrenamerbackup\vbdotnet"
Dim searchPattern As String = "*.wav"
Dim curDir As New DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)
Dim i As Integer = 1
For Each fi As FileInfo In curDir.GetFiles(searchPattern).OrderBy(Function(num) num.CreationTime)
    File.Move(fi.FullName, Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, "wavFile_" & i & ".wav"))
i += 1
Next
```

Comment: Are you sure you **need** Excel file? May be, comma-separated value is good enough? In any case, you can use `Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.xx` provider to create and fill Excel file. You can google for it - there are plenty examples

Comment: comma separated value is also fine, but how to log detail ( of both original file along with renamed file ) is my query ?

Comment: Add single line in your `for-each` using same variables to add to a list of log entries --> `myList.Add(fi.FullName & "," & Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, "wavFile_" & i & ".wav"))` And later write to file --> `File.WriteAllLines("c:\myLogFile.csv", myList)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. On inserting the above, I receive an error - 'myList' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Please suggest

Comment: So then declare `Dim myList As List(of string)`. You've got to do something :-)

Comment: Thanks, will try this out ( needless to say I am new to all this )

Comment: k, I tried this

Dim myList As New List(Of String)

It worked, but with 2 issues:

(1) It gives an output to .csv , but only log of one file, and none other.

(2) I receive this message on opening the .csv -  the file you are trying to open 'myLogFile.xls' is in a different format than specified by the file extension. verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. o you want to open the file now?  - I changed .csv to .xls, but same issue and message

Please suggest.

Comment: declare list before for-loop. do list.add in the loop. Excel is not especially great tool for modifying CSV files. Try to open excel and then file-open file as csv.

Comment: Thank you , working perfectly

Comment: thanks so much to T.S. for great help. Would I be asking too much if I take this question further. How to name the file back to original name ? Note: File is renamed and data pended to excel (as in above code), then it is processed, and finally (processed file) named back to original name.